# error: reference to non-static member function must be called when starting a thread

Tags: c++

I have this code that works.

```
void MediaRecorder::sendData(int timeslice)
{
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

    while (!s_finished)
    {
        requestData();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    }

}


ExceptionOr<void> MediaRecorder::startRecording(Optional<int> timeslice)
{
    ...

    if (timeslice)
    {
        sendData(timeslice.value());
    }


    return { };
}

ExceptionOr<void> MediaRecorder::stopRecording()
{


    s_finished = true;

    queueTaskKeepingObjectAlive(*this, TaskSource::Networking, [this] {
        if (!m_isActive || state() == RecordingState::Inactive)
            return;

        stopRecordingInternal();
        ASSERT(m_state == RecordingState::Inactive);
        m_private->fetchData([this, protectedThis = makeRef(*this)](auto&& buffer, auto& mimeType) {
            if (!m_isActive)
                return;

            dispatchEvent(BlobEvent::create(eventNames().dataavailableEvent, Event::CanBubble::No, Event::IsCancelable::No, buffer ? Blob::create(buffer.releaseNonNull(), mimeType) : Blob::create()));

            if (!m_isActive)
                return;

            dispatchEvent(Event::create(eventNames().stopEvent, Event::CanBubble::No, Event::IsCancelable::No));
        });
    });
    return { };
}

ExceptionOr<void> MediaRecorder::requestData()
{
    m_private->fetchData([this, protectedThis = makeRef(*this)](auto&& buffer, auto& mimeType) {
        if (!m_isActive)
            return;

        dispatchEvent(BlobEvent::create(eventNames().dataavailableEvent, Event::CanBubble::No, Event::IsCancelable::No, buffer ? Blob::create(buffer.releaseNonNull(), mimeType) : Blob::create()));
    });
    return { };
}
```

But I want to execute `sendData` in another thread. I tried

```
ExceptionOr<void> MediaRecorder::startRecording(Optional<int> timeslice)
{
    ...

    if (timeslice)
    {
        std::thread th1 (sendData, timeslice.value());
        th1.join();
    }


    return { };
}
```

But I get the error `reference to non-static member function` on this line `std::thread th1 (sendData, timeslice.value());`

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: As an aside to the given answer, you create the thread then join it immediately; would it not be more prudent (and less overhead) to simply call the function straight, e.g. `this->sendData(timeslice.value());` ?

Comment: I actually don't have to join it immediately, that something that I have to figure it out now that I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a non-static member function, the thread constructor needs the address of the member function, as well as an object pointer:

```
ExceptionOr<void> MediaRecorder::startRecording(Optional<int> timeslice)
{
    // ...
    std::thread th1 (&MediaRecorder::sendData, this, timeslice.value());
    // ...
}
```